# Display an image from a link in an ASP.Net GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I've saw ways to display binary images in a gridView - using repeaters, for example. I'm curious - how would you display an image which is stored as a link (i.e: `https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/ee/dc/cb/eedccb62388bb15b8ba6564372c71bac.jpg`) in a database? Is there any efficient, simple way to do it if I put the dataset source into the gridview (not using an imageField)?

Comment: Do you want to display image in **GridView** OR **Repeater** control? Please suggest.

Comment: No. You cannot display without using TemplateField or ImageField in Gridview just using image url.

Comment: @Dexterity in a GridView - i insert the Dataset as the source of the gridView.

Comment: @KiranVarsani In fact, you can display pure data with eval (i.e repeater controls in the dataset). I`m wondering if you can take it from the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below code to display image in **GridView** which stored as a link in database. I have used simple HTML **img** tag to display image.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvImages" CssClass="Gridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      HeaderStyle-BackColor="#7779AF" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="white">
 <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText = "Image Name" DataField="ImageURL" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <img src='<%# Eval("ImageURL") %>' Height="150" Width="150" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```